# image-border width adds up to image size (only in Chrome)

Tags: html, css, image, dictionary, area

I made a map that is used by an image but when I try to click the specified area, while having a border on the image, the area is moved by the border's width to the top and left.

I suspect the width of the border is added to the image's width and height. As far as I know this only happens in Chrome.
Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<map name="map1">
    <area shape="rect" coords="11,33,42,68" href="https://www.google.com/">
</map>
<style>
#imgStyle{
    border:20px solid black;
    border-image: url("border.png") 60 round;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <img src="start.gif" usemap="#map1" id="imgStyle">
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: Move the area 20px down and right?

Comment: @DamirKasipovic I could but this only happens in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

use `box-sizing` property to include the border size in total size of element::

```css
    #imgStyle{
    border:20px solid black;
    border-image: url("border.png") 60 round;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="imgStyle" style="width:200px;"
```

Comment: box-sizing dosen't do anything, I even tried changing the value to content-box but it's the same thing, it still works on firefox but not on chrome

Comment: Please Check the snippet above. Inspect the image and check it with 200px width including its border size.@EuLaurD. Perhaps you have another style which overwrites this style?

Comment: The problem is still persisting even with a set width or not and with the snippet. The only style I have is imgStyle and I'm not using style in my img tag so it shouldn't overwrite. I'm using the exact same page I posted in my initial post with the addition of your snippet and box-sizing. It's wierd because it looks like box-sizing isn't doing anything in either browsers. Does it work on your end?

Comment: in the snippet I have posted, When I inspect the image, the image size is 160px and there are two 20px border and total 200px. Make sure you have correct Doctype in your own document to support html5  @EuLaurD

Comment: It's the same thing even if I added <!DOCTYPE html>. I also inspected it and it gives me the same results that it gives you in all browsers but still the area is placed differently in Chrome.